# center on page responsive blocks with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

short question:  how does one center a responsive set of dynamic height div blocks on a page.   see simplified code below:

long: i have a set of data that goes into each block.  tables, graphs, etc.   the data is all mysql driven and dynamically changes all day long so the height of these blocks is not determined and is dynamic.   I want the blocks to auto position themselves as they do in the example code.  basic responsive page layout.  example: the pink table could be 50px or 5000px.   the float left is critical so that multiple block stack to the right as needed.

the challenge is for the blocks to be in the center of the page.  i can not seem to be able to figure that one out.

i have tried and research everything.   Flex does not seem to support this concept.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
.statusC, .statusC2 {
    float: left;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="statusC" style="height: 300px; width:500px; background-color:pink;">table</div>

    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:yellow;">progress</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:red;">clean</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:green;">stat</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:blue;">stat2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now I might misunderstood, centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: horizontally    aka right and left

Answer (score 0):

make a wrapper around the blocks and give it a width:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 300px; width:500px; background-color:pink;">table</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:yellow;">progress</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:red;">clean</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:green;">stat</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:blue;">stat2</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position :relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

the float of the blocks is granted.

https://jsfiddle.net/Marouen/0s2pwz5t/

Comment: Marouen  thank you for the quick response.    the problem is when you remove float:left the red clean block is no longer under yellow progress.   this has been my challenge...  that functionality is key to my design

Comment: Ok I see. I think you need media queries for that

Answer (score 0):

i found a TOTAL HACK that shows what i am trying to produce but not in a elegant way at all.   i hope there is a better solution.  there must be a solution that does not require setting the width...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.statusContainer2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.statusContainer3 {
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1999px) { .statusContainer3 { width:1500px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 1499px) { .statusContainer3 { width:1000px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) { .statusContainer3 { width:500px; } }

.statusC {
    float: left;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="statusContainer2" >
<div class="statusContainer3" >
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 300px; width:500px; background-color:pink;">table</div>

    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:yellow;">progress</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:red;">clean</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:green;">stat</div>
    <div class="statusC" style="height: 200px; width:500px; background-color:blue;">stat2</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You actually need to do as you did, there is no other way, unless you want start using script